# In Laravel Eloquent, how do you UPDATE a model with a cast encrypted field in a table with a composite primary key?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I finally found out how to update data in a table with a composite primary key in Laravel.  This is how. (Let's say the Vehicles table has a composite primary key of "make" and "model")

```php
Vehicle::where("make", $make)->where("model", $model)->update([
  "notes" => $notes,
]);
```

However, in my models/Vehicle.php file, I'm casting the "notes" columns to be encrypted, like this:

```php
public $casts = [
  'notes' => 'encrypted',
];
```

Putting the above two things together does not work.  The "notes" column will be saved with clear text, not encrypted.

However, if I create the record using `Vehicle::create(["make"=>$make, "model"=>$model, "notes"=>$notes])`, the "notes" column WILL be encrypted as expected when the record is created.  But once it's created, how can I update it?

p.s. In order to even get creating to work, I had to add this line to the model file:

```php
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this, but I would still like a solution that went through an actual Model.

```php
Vehicle::where("make", $make)->where("model", $model)->update([
  "notes" => Crypt::encrypt($notes, false),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use model events when creating or updating model:

```
public static function boot(): void
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(static function (Vehicle $vehicle) {
        $vehicle->notes = Crypt::encrypt($vehicle->notes, false),
    }

    static::updating(static function (Vehicle $vehicle) {
        if (!($changed = $vehicle->getDirty())) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!empty($changed['notes']) {
            $vehicle->notes = Crypt::encrypt($vehicle->notes, false),
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```